# c - Right justifying an int inside of a struct inside of another struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

How do I print out something from a struct within a struct. I want to print out '   $30'. Im getting segmentation errors.

```
typedef struct {
    int cost;
} prod_t;

typedef struct {
    prod_t *c;
} a_t;

 int
 main(int agrc, char **argv){
    a_t *storage = NULL;
    char buffer[1000];
    storage->c->cost = 30;

    sprintf(buffer, "$%d", storage->c->cost); 
    printf("%6s\n",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers in the first place?

Comment: Your question title and body are asking different questions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a_t *storage = NULL;
```

For all your pointers you need to allocate memory. Dereferencing  uninitialized/NULL pointers leads to undefined behavior.

```
a_t *storage = malloc(sizeof(a_t));
a_t->c = malloc(sizeof(prod_t));
```